# Can't access Child Nodes in Action Script 3 (AS3)

Tags: xml, flash, nodes, actionscript-3

I'm having trouble accessing any nodes inside my XML file. 
I can trace the whole file but once I try access any nodes inside of the XML the trace returns nothing.
Basically makes the XML data unusable.

AS3 Code:

```
    var citReq1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://serverstuff.com...format=xml");
citReq1.contentType = "text/xml";
citReq1.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var citLoad1:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
citLoad1.load (citReq1);

citLoad1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, citData)
function citData (event:Event):void{
    var xmlInfo:XML = new XML(event.target.data)

    trace(xmlInfo);
}
```

XML Returned:

```
<realtimeinformation xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07
/ie.dcc.rtpi2.services.publicservices.contracts.RealTimeBusInformation" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<errorcode>0</errorcode>
<errormessage/>
<numberofresults>1</numberofresults>
<stopid>243171</stopid>
<timestamp>07/12/2013 14:42:57</timestamp>
<results>
<result>
<arrivaldatetime>07/12/2013 14:47:00</arrivaldatetime>
<duetime>4</duetime>
<departuredatetime>07/12/2013 14:47:00</departuredatetime>
<departureduetime>4</departureduetime>
<scheduledarrivaldatetime>07/12/2013 14:47:00</scheduledarrivaldatetime>
<scheduleddeparturedatetime>07/12/2013 14:47:00</scheduleddeparturedatetime>
<destination>C.I.T.</destination>
<destinationlocalized>C.I.T.</destinationlocalized>
<origin>Kent Station</origin>
<originlocalized>Kent Station</originlocalized>
<direction>I</direction>
<operator>BE</operator>
<additionalinformation/>
<lowfloorstatus>no</lowfloorstatus>
<route>205</route>
<sourcetimestamp>07/12/2013 14:17:44</sourcetimestamp>
</result>
</results>
</realtimeinformation>
```

I did a lot of searching, found 1 other person with this problem, their solution involved setting namespaces. When I try that I can access the nodes in the XML, but clicking any other button on screen gives me
An Actionscript error popup:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Final_fla::ns is not defined.
at Final_fla::MainTimeline/menu()[Final_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:125]
```

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: On your Frame 1 at line 125, what do you have?

Comment: 125 was the line setting the namesake.
I'm now working off a local XML file which works without changing any code apart from the URL request.

Seems to be the server causing the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You haven't demonstrated where & how you're failing to get the data from your XML.  However, I can say that the way you've written it now, `xmlInfo` is a local variable to your `citData` listener; meaning: you haven't saved it anywhere persistent, and the moment you leave the listener, any reference to `xmlInfo` will return `null`.

Try this:

```
loadXML("http://serverstuff.com...format=xml");

function loadXML(request:String):void {
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(request);
    req.contentType = "text/xml";
    req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, citData)
    loader.load(req);
}

var xmlInfo:XML;
function citData(e:Event):void{
    xmlInfo = new XML(e.target.data)
    trace(xmlInfo);

    exampleExternalFunction();
}

function exampleExternalFunction():void {
    trace(xmlInfo.timestamp)
}
```

I'm a little rusty on xml references, so you may need `xmlInfo.realtimeinformation.timestamp`.  Regardless, in this example, we've stored the XML in a persistent scope which is available to `exampleExternalFunction()` thereby allowing it to reference the properties we received from the XML.